# Python : is it ok returning both boolean and string?

Tags: python

Original Question

I have made a function which is waiting for a particular string to appear on a serial port, and returns all character read until the string was found, or false if not. This is quite convenient, but I was wondering if it is considered bad practice or not ?

Clarification :

The primary goal is to wait for a **particular** string to appear in a given amount of time. Except for IO error, the possible outcome is True (the string did appear) or False
The secondary goal is to get the entire output, because there might be information that I would like to parse for before the actual answer that is looked for. I thought may be I could combine the primary and secondary goal in one return value.

```
def MyFunc(s, timeout) :
    test = get_some_input(timeout)
    if test.endswith(s)
        return test
    else
        return False
```

Edit : Another proposed answer is to raise an exception. I don't think it is a good idea, because the timeout is an expected behaviour. I mean, if there is a parameter for specifying a timeout, then a timeout is a possible outcome, and not an exception.

Edit 2 :
Since I need to store the input, maybe using a class is the right solution. The wait for function has a clear return value, yet the entire string that was read until timeout is also accessible.

```
class Parser :
        def __init__(self, sport_name):
                self.currentMsg = ''
                self.ser = serial.Serial(sport_name, 115200)
        def WaitFor(self, s, timeOut=None):
                self.ser.timeout = timeOut
                self.currentMsg = ''
                while self.currentMsg.endswith(s) != True :
                        # should add a try catch here
                        c=self.ser.read()
                        if c != '' :
                               self.currentMsg += c
                        else :
                                print 'timeout waiting for ' + s
                                return False
                return True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be better to return a string AND a boolean (as in the title) instead of returning a string OR a boolean. You shouldn't have to figure out what the return value means. It should be totally explicit and orthogonal issues should be separated into different variables.

```
(okay,value) = get_some_input(blah);
if (okay): print value
```

I tend not to return tuples a lot, because it feels funny.  But it's perfectly valid to do so.

Returning "None" is a valid solution, already mentioned here.

Comment: That orthogonal thing is perfectly right. So returning a tuple would be a good solution, however I am not yet very comfortable with this, plus using a class allows me to embed a serial port in it, and allows for further extension.

Comment: so, what should be the value if okay is False?

Comment: @SilentGhost: value is always an input read so far (until string found or timeout occurred).

Comment: if okay is false, value could be an empty string or whatever input that came until timeout occured

Comment: If okay is false, the value is undefined.  Could be None. Could be 42.  I kinda like None.

Answer (score 28):

Would it not be more suitable to return a `None` instead of `False`?

Comment: but as described in other answers, an exception is even more Pythonic.

Comment: An exception isn't Pythonic in this case. Look at the behavior of the standard library -- in particular select.select and re.match.

Comment: I think both solution are good: returning None or raising an exception. It depends on the overall way you handle failure or abnormal conditions in your program.

Answer (score 12):

I believe the orthodox Python design would be to return None. The [manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) says:

> None
>
> This type has a single value. There is
>   a single object with this value. This
>   object is accessed through the
>   built-in name None. It is used to
>   signify the absence of a value in many
>   situations, e.g., it is returned from
>   functions that don’t explicitly return
>   anything. Its truth value is false.

Answer (score 6):

The convenient thing is to return an empty string in this case.

Besides an empty string in Python will evaluate to False anyway. So you could call it like:

```
if Myfunc(s, timeout):
    print "success"
```

Addition: As pointed out by S.Lott the true Pythonic way is to return None. Though I choose to return strings in string related funcs. A matter of preference indeed.

Also I assume the caller of Myfunc only cares about getting a string to manipulate on - empty or not. If the caller needs to check about timeout issues, etc.. it's better to use exceptions or returning None.

Comment: The trouble with this design is that it doesn't distinguish between timeout in one case, and s and test being equal to "".

Comment: -1: Not very Pythonic at all.  Empty strings are still strings.  None is better.  An exception is better still.

Comment: @utku karatas: Not a matter of preference -- it's a matter of *meaning*.  A zero-length string means you read zero until delimiter or end-of-file.  A None means you did not read.

Comment: @S.Lott: I assume the case where the caller of Myfunc only cares about getting a string to manipulate on - empty or not.

Comment: @utku karatas: string is one thing -- timeout is not a string.  It remains a matter of meaning.

Comment: Sometimes, for a program, it's equivalent to read an empty to string and not to read anything. So, if the distinction does not matter, returning an empty string makes sense because the whole program is more streamlined.

Comment: Basically, the question boils down to: Is reading nothing ok, is reading nothing a special case to handle or is reading nothing a fatal error? In case 1, return the empty string, in case 2, return a tuple or a class "read enough" "string read", in the third case, throw an exception.

Comment: Exceptions don't have to indicate a fatal error.  The language itself uses exceptions to indicate all kinds of situations that are not only non-fatal but aren't even errors at all.

Comment: A note for myself and other readers: The question was edited multiple times. This answer was posted (and edited) in the times of the first edit. I.e. the question was: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b4d379e5-f83f-46f6-a88f-0c3e1c7bc1f4/view-source

Answer (score 4):

Maybe if you return a tuple like (False, None) and (True, test) it would be better, as you can evaluate them separatedly and not add unnecesary complexity.

EDIT: Perhaps the string that appeared on the serial port is "" (maybe expected), so returning True can say that it arrived that way.

Comment: I'd rather go the @jelovirt way: testing for None is unambiguous and does not really add complexity.

Comment: I've always like the python tuples for returning multiple values. +1.

Comment: I like this idea, returning a control flag in the same value field doesn't sound right to me. 

In that kind of situations, you have the risk that in the future the valid values change (like you said, allowing null) and the control flag become invalid.

Answer (score 4):

You could return the string if it arrived in time, or raise a suitable exception indicating time out.

Comment: Even if raising an exception in Python is inexpensive compared to other languages, I don't think that providing functionality using them is a great idea.

Comment: +1: Exceptions make more sense in this case -- you had an "exception" condition -- a timeout.

Comment: In fact I have used this pattern a lot and very successfully in a project that uses communication via serial ports etc. The time out exception handles retries, resend conditions quite well.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Ber's point, you might want to take something else into account.  If you use an empty string or None, you leave the door open for bugs of the "dumb" variety.  On the other hand, if you raise an exception, you're forcing the execution of whatever operation is running to be aborted.

For example, consider the following code:

```
result = MyFunc(s, timeout)
if result[0] == 'a':
    do_something()
```

This will raise an exception if the operation timed out and got either an empty string or None.  So you'd have to change that to:

```
result = MyFunc(s, timeout)
if result and result[0] == 'a':
    do_something()
```

These kinds of changes tend to add up and make your code more difficult to understand.

Of course, I'm sure that your answer to this will be something along the lines of "I won't do that" or "that won't happen" to which my answer is "Even if you don't run into it with this function, you will eventually if you make a habit of doing this."  These kinds of bugs are almost always the result of corner cases that you don't usually think about.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use case for Python generators.  The `yield` keyword provides a simple way to iterate over discrete sets without returning the whole thing at once:

```
def MyFunc(s, timeout) :
    test = get_some_input(timeout)
    while test.endswith(s)
        yield test
        test = get_some_input(timeout)

for input in MyFunc(s, timeout):
    print input
```

The key here is there is no return value to specify the end of input; instead, you simply reach the end of the iterator.  More information on generators [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).